Is it permitted to supply a value for a TypeVar in Python?
Consider the following generic type:
Response(Generic[ResponseT])
The type var is defined as follows:
ResponseT = TypeVar("ResponseT")
I have seen Response[None] usages without VS Code (Pylance/Pyright) complaining about type issues.
So, is it permitted to supply arbitrary values for TypeVar? I thought that only types could be provided as arguments, but None is not a type

None is special, it is both a value and can be used as a type. You will get an error for Response[3], for example.

Actually, Pyright shows no error for Response[3]

Really? It does here: https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoDiApikSEgMYA0UAKokQGoCGIAUGwEpEDOOKPIrSgBeOgxYgAFACJufMAKEyAlBzYUANsx48o8-oKnFS5CgG0DiwbQC6KgFxsoLqAh091ADwf7ehonMAZlsgA
